# How to add data along with dojo get request

Tags: dojo

Here is the example of dojo post request

```
require(["dojo/request", "dojo/domReady!"],
      function (request) {
           request.post("newjsp.jsp", {
                                    data: {
                                        color: "blue"
                                    }
          }).then(function (response) {
                  alert(response);
          }, function (error) {
                  alert(error);
          });
   });
```

in this code i have attched attribute color as data

How to do this in dojo get request

```
require(["dojo/request", "dojo/domReady!"],
      function (request) {
           request.get("newjsp.jsp", {
                                    data: {
                                        color: "blue"
                                    }
          }).then(function (response) {
                  alert(response);
          }, function (error) {
                  alert(error);
          });
   });
```

This code is not working 
How to fix??

Answer (score 1):

Use `content` instead of `data`.

```
require(["dojo/request", "dojo/domReady!"],
      function (request) {
           request.get("newjsp.jsp", {
                                    query: {
                                        color: "blue"
                                    }
          }).then(function (response) {
                  alert(response);
          }, function (error) {
                  alert(error);
          });
   });
```

Comment: The server is not getting value of attribute color from request

Comment: Use `query` instead of `content`. I was testing on earlier version. This should work.